# Sencha Architect - creating a screen with a form

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Just started to look at sencha touch

Could anyone please explain where you would use "FieldSet, FormPanel and containers"

For Example: a form with title, textfield and submit button?

A login screen ...

```
Title: Login
TextField: username
PasswordField: password
Button: submit
```

1) will this login screen be in a container, a field set and/or formpanel?

2) What about a form without a title? just textfield, button, or just a screen with title, list of data?

Answer (score 0):

I think example code will be helpful for you:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginSiteContainer', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.loginsitecontainer',

config: {
    id: 'loginform',
    url: 'som_url',
    items: [            
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    instructions: 'Login using existing account. Password is case sensitive.',
                    title: 'Login details',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'login',
                            itemId: 'login',
                            label: 'Login'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            id: 'password',
                            itemId: 'password',
                            label: 'Password'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'Login',
                            itemId: 'Login',
                            margin: '0.1em',
                            ui: 'confirm',
                            text: 'Login',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: [            
        {
            fn: 'onLoginTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#Login'
        }
    ]
},


onLoginTap: function(button, e, options) {
// login function here
}
```

});